# enabling JPA static weaving(eclipselink)

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, eclipselink

I am new to Eclipselink. I have written couple of web services(deployed in Tomcat) using Eclipselink/Java. These web services use several entity classes. In order to improve the web services performance I am trying to use static weaving. I learned that I can enable this either from command line or using Eclipselink weave ant script. Since I use eclipse and build my WAR from eclipse, I am not sure where should use the "weave" Ant task within Eclipse IDE. So, I tried the command line option like this:

```
java org.eclipse.persistence.tools.weaving.jpa.StaticWeave -persistenceinfo c:\eclipse 
\workspace\employeeModel\src -classpath c:\eclipse\workspace\employeeModel\src -log 
c:\log\weave.log -loglevel FINEST c:\eclipse\workspace\employeeModel\src c:\eclipse 
\workspace\employeeModel\src
```

[The last two paths in the command, c:\eclipse\workspace\employeeModel\src c:\eclipse\workspace\employeeModel\src refers source and target respectively]

When I ran this, it logged the following in the log file:
    [EL Finest]: 2012-03-05  17:22:49.806--ServerSession(8880493)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--property=eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-column-names; default value=false
[EL Finer]: 2012-03-05 17:22:49.837--ServerSession(8880493)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Searching for default mapping file in file:/c:/eclipse/workspace/employeeModel/src/
[EL Finer]: 2012-03-05 17:22:49.852--ServerSession(8880493)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Searching for default mapping file in file:/c:/eclipse/workspace/employeeModel/src/

From the log it looks like the staticWeave didn't complete successfully. But it didn't produce any error on the command line either.

Since I used same path for both source(.java) and target, the staticWeave did overwrite my source files(.java files). I am not sure if staticWeave(command I ran above) will produce the class files(.class) or will overwrite the source code(.java).

I am also not sure if what I have done is right. How can I verify if the static weaving actually enabled? If what I have done is not right, could somebody help me to understand on how to use the Eclipselink weave ant task in Eclipse IDE? or the mistake I am doing on the command line option. 
Also, I would like to know if the staticWeave will actually overwrite the source files or create the byte codes(.class files).

I spent several hours to make this work, but with no success. Could someone shed some light on this?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Static weaving weave the .class files, and output .class files.  It does not work on .java files.  Normally you give it a jar file, and it outputs a new jar file.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your response. How can I check if I successfully enabled static weaving?

Answer (score 3):

Add this code to your `build.xml` file:

```
<target name="-post-jar">
        <antcall target="weaving"/>
</target>
<target name="define.task" description="New task definition for EclipseLink static weaving">
<taskdef name="weave" classname="org.eclipse.persistence.tools.weaving.jpa.StaticWeaveAntTask"/>
</target>
<target name="weaving" description="perform weaving" depends="define.task">
        <weave  source="C:\<projectpath>\dist\${ant.project.name}.jar"
                target="C:\<projectpath>\dist\woven-${ant.project.name}.jar"
                persistenceinfo="D:\<projectpath>\lib\persistence.jar"
                loglevel="FINE"
                log="C:\<projectpath>\weaver.log">
            <classpath>
            </classpath>
        </weave>
</target>
```

In the code, change `<projectpath>` with the path where your source code is located. And the `persistenceinfo` is pointing the another jar (persistence.jar) which only contains the `persistence.xml` I use, as I share the same persistence.xml file among several projects. If you don't use a separated jar for the persistence.xml file, then remove that property and use `persistencexml=<path-to-persistence.xml-file>\META-INF\persistence.xml`.

Also, you'll need to add the files `eclipselink.jar` and `javax.persistence...jar` to the Ant classpath. If you're using Netbeans, go to `Tools | Options | Java | Ant` there you can add those files to the classpath.

With the previous code, every time you compile it will generate a new file with the prefix `woven-` which is your new woven jar file.

Answer (score 1):

If maven project, you could use this maven plugin to weave the jar

```
 <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>de.empulse.eclipselink</groupId>
            <artifactId>staticweave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>weave</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <persistenceXMLLocation>META-INF/persistence.xml</persistenceXMLLocation>
                        <logLevel>FINE</logLevel>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
                    <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

**See Also : [EclipseLink - Configuring Static Weaving](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use an exploded directory structure instead of a jar for your class files to be woven if you want.